# Maximal Hamming distance

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory, combinatorics-on-words

Here is a combinatorial problem: let $\Sigma=\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ be an alphabet and we consider any words over $\Sigma$ of length $n$. We also define over the set of such words the Hamming distance: $$d(\omega,\omega')=\#\{i\in \{1,\ldots,n\} \vert a_i\neq b_i\}$$ where $\omega=a_1\ldots a_{n}$ and $\omega'=b_1\ldots b_n$ are two words.

The questions are the following:

- Let $\omega_0$ be the word built with only one letter: $$\omega_0=\underbrace{\alpha\ldots \alpha}_{n \text{ times}}$$ what is the cardinality of a biggest set $\Omega(\omega_0)$ of words of length $n$ containing $\omega_0$ and such that $\forall \omega,\omega'\in \Omega(\omega_0), \ d(\omega,\omega')=n-1$ ?
- What if we ask the same question for words of length $n+1$ where $\omega_0=\underbrace{\alpha\ldots \alpha}_{n+1 \text{ times}}$ and $\Omega(\omega_0)$ is a maximal set of words of length $n+1$ containing $\omega_0$ such that $\forall \omega,\omega'\in \Omega(\omega_0), \ d(\omega,\omega')=n-1$?

It seems that the result is the same and depends only on the cardinality of the alphabet but I don't know how to prove it neatly. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that every vector must have $\alpha$ in the $i^{th}$ position for exactly one $i$ between $1\leq i\leq n$.  Then since the largest set of words of length $n-1$ on $n-1$ letters with pairwise distance $n-1$ has size exactly $n-1$, we see that $$|\Omega(\omega_0)|\leq n(n-1).$$ (Similarly for your second question we obtain the upper bound $(n+1)n(n-1)/2$) However I doubt that this upper bound is tight.

Comment: The fact that at least one letter does not change is not really clear to me. Can you explain ? I think with this fact, and using induction one can compute explicitly the cardinality of $\Omega(\omega_0)$.